# deploying ejb-module for ObjectDB fails: PersistenceProvider not found

Tags: java, maven, ejb, wildfly, objectdb

I have two almost identical projects (both created with maven, both very simple) where one deploys without any problems, the other gives me a PersistenceException:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.objectdb.jpa.Provider' not found
```

And I just don't see what I am missing here.

The **working** project is web application. I got it from the [JPA Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/netbeans/ee). I has a simple `jsp` page, servlet, a database entity and a stateless bean for the entity.

When I deploy it, I can call the jsp, enter some example data which will be passed to the servlet, which then again writes the data into the **ObjectDB** database using the bean and the corresponding entity. simple.

The **not working** project is supposed to be an **ejb-module** with only the `entity` and the `stateless bean`.

But when I try deploying it on my local WildFly server, I get the above error.
I also noticed, that the compiled `ejb.jar` has only a few kilobytes while the web application `war` files uses 1.4 MB. So I guess that it includes the necessary `objectdb.jar` library. But I can get the ejb.jar to include the library.

Here is my maven **pom.xml** of the *working web application* (sorry it's long):

```
<groupId>com.me</groupId>
<artifactId>ObjectDBMavenTest</artifactId>
<version>2.01.1-00001</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>ObjectDBMavenTest</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1_06</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>objectdb</id>
        <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.objectdb.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And as a comparison the **pom.xml** of the ***not*** working ejb project:

```
<groupId>com.me</groupId>
<artifactId>Database</artifactId>
<version>2.01.1-00001</version>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<name>Database</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1_06</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>objectdb</id>
        <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.objectdb.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Frankly I don't see much of a difference, only that one is going to be a *war* file the other a *jar*.

If it makes any difference, here are my two *persistence.xml* files.

**working**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ObjectDBMavenTestPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>com.objectdb.jpa.Provider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="$objectdb/db/guests.odb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and **not working**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyDatabase" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>com.objectdb.jpa.Provider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="$objectdb/db/myDatabase.odb"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow just writing about it here on SO helped me find my error :) I just have to force maven to include all dependencies. This can be done by including the following plugin into the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
 ...
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now the needed `objectdb.jar` library is included as dependency to the ejb.jar and I finally can deploy it without errors. Thanks everyone for caring :)